# Understanding the code..!

Tags: vb.net

You cannot vote on your own post
0

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Sockets
Imports System.Text
Public Class SNMP

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub
    Public Function [get](ByVal request As String, ByVal host As String, ByVal community As String, ByVal mibstring As String) As Byte()
        Dim packet As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
        Dim mib As Byte() = New Byte(1023) {}
        Dim snmplen As Integer
        Dim comlen As Integer = community.Length
        Dim mibvals As String() = mibstring.Split("."c)
        Dim miblen As Integer = mibvals.Length
        Dim cnt As Integer = 0, temp As Integer, i As Integer
        Dim orgmiblen As Integer = miblen
        Dim pos As Integer = 0
        ' Convert the string MIB into a byte array of integer values
        ' Unfortunately, values over 128 require multiple bytes
        ' which also increases the MIB length
        For i = 0 To orgmiblen - 1
            temp = Convert.ToInt16(mibvals(i))
            If temp > 127 Then
                mib(cnt) = Convert.ToByte(128 + (temp \ 128))
                mib(cnt + 1) = Convert.ToByte(temp - ((temp \ 128) * 128))
                cnt += 2
                miblen += 1
            Else
                mib(cnt) = Convert.ToByte(temp)
                cnt += 1
            End If
        Next
        snmplen = 29 + comlen + miblen - 1
```

If somebody help me understand the following pat of code i'd be obliged..

```
For i = 0 To orgmiblen - 1
        temp = Convert.ToInt16(mibvals(i))
        If temp > 127 Then
            mib(cnt) = Convert.ToByte(128 + (temp \ 128))
            mib(cnt + 1) = Convert.ToByte(temp - ((temp \ 128) * 128))
            cnt += 2
            miblen += 1
        Else
            mib(cnt) = Convert.ToByte(temp)
            cnt += 1
        End If
```

Answer (score 2):

It puts a value in the array using a variation of varint encoding.

Using the varint encoding, a value is stored seven bits at a time starting with the least significant bits, and using the eighth bit as stop bit when the remaining value is zero. This is the method that the `BinaryWriter.Write7BitEncodedInt` method is using.

The code above only handles a value using no more than 14 bits, and stores the most significant bits first, using the eighth bit as a continue flag instead of a stop flag.

I.e. a value less than 128 is stored in a single byte, while a value that is 128 or greater is stored with the most significant seven bits first, with the eighth bit set to flag that it's a two-byte value, then the other seven bits.